# Removing rstudio and its user from the system

Tags: sudo, rstudio

I installed **rstudio** on my system, but I don't need it now. It has created its own user. Whenever I turn my system on, two users appear on the screen. This has happened only after installing rstudio. I don't want rstudio and its user as well.

I successfully uninstalled rstudio by `sudo apt-get purge rstudio`.

Still the login page is showing two users. Then I logged in to the second "rstudio" user and opened its terminal.

When I used `deluser` command there, I got this error.

`rstudio@ubuntu-Vostro-15-3568:~$ sudo deluser
rstudio is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

Please help me to delete this user.

Comment: How exactly did you install it?

Comment: Via terminal. sudo apt -y install r-base

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the same way? `sudo apt remove r-base`

Comment: Highly unlikely this added a user!

Comment: @vanadium you are right. Actually immediately after it I installed rstudio, which created a user. Kindly read my edited question.

Comment: On my 16.04 LTS system I have installed `rstudio` and other R packages. But I do not have `rstudio` user in my system. Why do you think that `rstudio` user was created during RStudio installation? Do you use RStudio Server? Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep rstudio` and `getent passwd rstudio` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo apt-get purge r-base`. 
This works like `apt remove` but also deletes configuration files.

After that, issue the following commands: 
`sudo deluser --remove-all-files rstudio` 
`sudo deluser --group --remove-all-files rstudio` 
This will remove the system user created by the installer, which is not automatically removed by the uninstaller.

Comment: R was successfully uninstalled, but the username still appears. Terminal shows this error = /usr/sbin/deluser: The user `Niranjan' does not exist.

Comment: `deluser` doesn't exists, what OS is this?

Comment: It says user that I mentioned doesn't exist. My OS is ubuntu 18.04. I use xfce4 desktop environment.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen `deluser` is a wrapper around `userdel` on Debian-based distributions of Linux, including Ubuntu. If you're using Ubuntu -- or any distro based thereon -- and somehow `deluser` is missing, you can install it with `sudo apt-get install adduser`. If you're not using Ubuntu, answers in Ask Ubuntu may not apply to your situation. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much everyone for your efforts.
I was putting username when I was asked for user. I checked the command that I used to add the user. ie.
`sudo adduser rstudio`
As I was putting the user"name" in the command, it wasn't working.
I simply used
`sudo deluser rstudio`
and I got this!

`Removing user 'rstudio' ...
Warning: group 'rstudio' has no more members.
Done.`

Now everything is fine. :)

Comment: Also remove the group rstudio.